# How to request IPv4 address from a machine name?

Tags: linux, ip, mapping, hostname, ipv4

In my linux cluster, I've got a bunch of hostnames, while my network management log shows ip addresses(they changes sometimes according to dns).

My question is: how to quickly find out the ipv4 of some hostname, without using "ping xxxxx" to get ip address and Ctrl+c to stop it. I wish to write a simple script like:

```
myCommand hostname1
myCommand hostname2
myCommand hostname3
myCommand hostname4
myCommand hostname5
```

Which will print hostname to ipaddress mapping for me(for hostname1-5)

So how to write this "myCommand" command or shell script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `host` tool from [bind-tools](http://www.isc.org/software/bind):

```
$ host -4 -t A stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.129.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.1.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.193.69
stackoverflow.com has address 151.101.65.69
```

Or `dig` tool from the same package:

```
$ dig -4 -t A stackoverflow.com +short
151.101.129.69
151.101.1.69
151.101.193.69
151.101.65.69
```

Comment: Thanks, the host -4 -t A command always work for me, but dig doesn't always work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function get_ip {
    echo $1
    getent hosts $1 | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed 's/^/  /g'
    echo
}
```

Usage:

```
get_ip unix.stackexchange.com
get_ip hostname1
get_ip hostname2
```